# Перегрузка оператора сложения класса с двумя полями

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

```
class KOMPLEX {
    double re, im;
    public:
    KOMPLEX(double a, double b) : re(a), im(b) {cout<<"konstructor: " << re <<","<< im; }
    KOMPLEX() : re(1), im(1) {cout<<"konstructor: " << re<<","<< im;} //по умолчанию
    ~KOMPLEX() { } // Деструктор
    void input(); // метод ввода с клавиатуры
    void result(); // метод вывода на экран
    void plus(); // сложение
    KOMPLEX & operator + (const KOMPLEX& b) {
        re += b.re; im += b.im;
        new KOMPLEX c (re, im);
        return 
            cout << c.re << " " << c.im;
    }
    };
    int main() {
    KOMPLEX a(2,2);
    KOMPLEX b(3,3);
    a+b;
    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку

```
prog.cpp: In member function ‘KOMPLEX& KOMPLEX::operator+(const KOMPLEX&)’:
prog.cpp:16:15: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘c’
   new KOMPLEX c (re, im);
           ^
prog.cpp:18:12: error: ‘c’ was not declared in this scope
cout << c.re << " " << c.im;
```

Что я сломал?(

Comment: `new KOMPLEX c (re, im);` - зачем тут `c`?

Comment: если вы хотите получить ответ, то очень желательно в теме и ключевых словах указывать, на каком языке программирования вы пишите

Comment: Мб, `c = new ...`?

Answer (score 1):

логично, потому что синтаксис неверный.

Самое  близкое к тому, что Вы хотите видимо будет такое

```
KOMPLEX operator + (const KOMPLEX& b) {
    return KOMPLEX(re+b.re, im+b.im);
}
```

(остальной код ещё тот ужас)

Comment: Может своим "ko" это он вас так тонко тролит :)